# Use of relationship and ForeignKey modules in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a little confused over the use of the two modules from SQLAlchemy. This is the code I have:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Restaurant(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'restaurant'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

class MenuItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'menu_item'
    name =Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    course = Column(String(250))
    restaurant_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('restaurant.id'))
    restaurant = relationship(Restaurant)
```

I understand that ForeignKey is used to define the foreign key relationship between the restaurant_id column of menu_item table and the id column of restaurant table. But why then is restaurant = relationship(Restaurant) used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`restaurant_id` will refer to an id (the column value). `restaurant` will refer to a `Restaurant` instance that will be lazy loaded from the db on access (or eager loaded if you set up the right stuff earlier). If you set `backref` on the `relationship` you can also access a list of `MenuItem` objects from a `Restaurant`.